# Gallio error "An exception was thrown while exploring tests."

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mbunit, gallio

Hi I have a test project with Gallio 3.2 b.435 within VisualStudio 2010. Every time I launch any test the output windows pops out.

this is the error message

```
[error] An exception was thrown while exploring tests.
Location: C:\xxxxxxx(73)
Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
```

this is the code at the line specified

```
71: [Test, ExpectedException(typeof(RulesException<Story>))]
72: public void CanNotSaveItemIfInvalid()
73: {
74:     var story= new Story{ Id = 100, Tilte= "test" };
75:      repository.Save(story, new MembershipUser());
76: }
```

This error isthrown no metter what test is under testing (the project contains 700 test)
Of course ;) the test compiles and passes and I cannot understand the error.

bye Stefano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is a [known issue](http://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/issues/detail?id=697). It's due to a bug in the early version of Mono.Cecil (v0.6) that was used by the Gallio core engine.  It has been fixed recently: Gallio is now using Mono.Cecil v0.9.

Please try out the [latest version](http://gallio.org/Downloads.aspx) of Gallio (v3.2.2)